# How to identify document in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

You can put your documents in SP - cool, but, when its time to reorganize folders structure what I should do with old links?

Is there a way how to identify document instead of using URL where path to the document is used? I need something like permanent link: http://mysharepoint/doc-123, where 123 is the document identifier.

I need URL to the document which doesn't depend on folders where the document is published. Are there solutions?

Answer (score 1):

SP2010 will offer a unique per site collection identifier for each document that you can use with a built-in redirector service.

Comment: Thanks, thus previous versions of SP can't do that? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an URL Shortener solution and combine it with a SharePoint (Designer) Workflow or Event Receiver.

I have worked on a [product](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-URL-Shortener.aspx) that can be used in combination with SharePoint and can be used via web services, workflows as well as the user interface.

As your need is quite specific you may need to do a little bit of extra coding. If you don't have access to Visual Studio or prefer to use SharePoint Designer workflows for everything than have a look at the [Workflow Power Pack](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/create-shortened-tinyurl-links-from.html).

Comment: Great, but still one question: do shorten URL depends on where the file published? As I saw on your site (second screenshot on product page) original URL depends on path "PDFConverterTest/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems"

If I move the document to another site (e.g. WordConverterTest), do your method still allow to open the document using http://go.local/x3e ?

Comment: You would need to update the location of the existing short url, which is something you can do. It would be up to you to make sure this code is executed whenever the file is moved, I don't know which process controls this. Alternatively you could save the short URL in a hidden field on the file so you can periodically iterate over files and update associated short URLs to the new location.

Comment: I see, this is something I dont want to track and spend time on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create database table that contains the mapping to the files (you'll need to update there when the file changes) 
the table should contain url wanted to route | url destination
then you could implement an HttpModule that reads that url and then redirects to the one in the table, however that will cost you overall performance so you could create a pattern and only do that when it matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2007 you could create a redirecting page that takes the unique id of a document as query parameter. Use this id to get the document `SPContext.Current.Web.GetFile(id)` and redirect the response with the file url.